# Отглагольные прилагательные

Tags: причастия

Всегда ли слово "смущена" пишется с одним Н?

Answer (score 3):

1) В большинстве случаев причастие **"смущена"** пишется с одной буквой Н:

Но она была **смущена**, смеялась и шутила уклончиво. [А. С. Грин. Ива (1923)]

2) Очень редко (в старых текстах) встречается краткое прилагательное **"смущенна"**, обычно при наличии однородных отношений с другими прилагательными:

"Жена, грехами отягчения, К владыке своему течет **бледна, смущенна**, ― [Ю. Н. Тынянов. Пушкин (1935-1943)]  **Смущенна, неподвижна**, долгое время в молчании пребывает. [Д. И. Фонвизин. Иосиф (1769)]   Но воин храбр бывает тогда; когда его совесть не зазорна, **не смущенна** мысль, и чувствует справедливость стоящую с своея стороны. [архиепископ Платон (Левшин). (1770)]

Answer (score 1):

> Всегда ли слово "смущена" пишется с одним Н?

Словари допускают написание и с двумя Н.

См. [**"Русский орфографический словарь"**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x):

> **смущённый**; *кр. ф.* **-ён, -ена** и (*выражающий смущение*) **-ён, -ённа** (её улыбка **смущённа**)

Answer (score 0):

Эти два варианта *различаются по смыслу* (краткое причастие или прилагательное): была смуще**н**а = **её смутило** некое действие или обстоятельство (внутреннее ощущение или чьё-то утверждение о её состоянии); была смущё**нн**а = у неё был **смущённый вид** (вероятно, её что-то смутило или смущало).